# Кастомный Identity не обращается к /Identity/Account/Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-identity-3

Я пробовал разные варианты кастомного identity, даже мелкие отступления в сторону от типового решения (допустим, решил поменять тип поля для User Id на int или сделать вход в приложение не по емейлу,  по логину) вызывают одну неприятную особенность в asp.net core 2.1

При указании корректного адреса для страниц login, logout (например в _LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@inject SignInManager<CustomUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<CustomUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Logout</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

Ссылка почему-то отображается некорректно: вместо /Identity/Account/Login будет ссылка на /Account/Login - при этом если в браузере вбить правильный адрес, то страница логина есть.

В явном виде это в типовом решении нигде не указывается, но и при кастомизации я меняю такие места, в которых это не может настраиваться, тогда где же?

Это не в Startup.cs настройки идентити:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

И это (там же) не настройки маршрутов:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "areas",
    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Это не настройки \Areas\Identity\IdentityHostingStartup.cs (если он вообще есть) - там пусто:

```
[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(WebApplication2.Areas.Identity.IdentityHostingStartup))]
namespace WebApplication2.Areas.Identity
{
    public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда где же? Такое впечатление, что дефолтный identity прошивает где-то area=Identity, но где этот код и почему он слетает при кастомизации - я не понимаю.

Есть какие-то идеи?

Answer (score 1):

Я в общем, так и не понял, где это настраивается, оставлю промежуточный результат для практического применения.

Нужно [после](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633896/asp-net-core-identity-change-login-url) настроек идентити настроить заново все url для страниц входа-выхода:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    // ...
});
```

Это работает, хотя переопределять приходится несколько адресов, а не указывать определённую area.

Ссылки по теме:

- [Change routing in ASP.NET Core Identity UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682108/change-routing-in-asp-net-core-identity-ui)

--

Апдейт от 2021 года

Я натолкнулся на эту тему с примерно похожей ошибкой когда делал новый проект на net 5 (и подумал "какие хорошие ответы", не разглядев, что половина написанного была мной же самим).

В общем, более вдумчиво читая документацию я увидел незамеченный мной ранее `.AddDefaultUI()` в конфигурации IdentityHostingStartup - и именно его добавление позволяет не хардкодить пути как выше, работает во всех версиях 2.x, 3.x и 5.0:

```
public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultUI();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, так это понятно, вы указываете "asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index", вам и будет показывать линк - ".../Account/Manage/Index", если хотите нормальный линк, лучше сделать так

```
<a asp-area="Identity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Register</a>....
```

И обязательно над контролером должно стоять наименование области

```
  [Area("Identity")]
  public class BLABLA : Controller
```

Comment: В новом identity нет контроллеров, всё переделали на razor pages.

Comment: А вы пробовали добавить services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.AllowAreas = true;
});